# On ajax success, change another link value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple jquery voting system where users click a heart icon and a value is updated with the amount of likes the post currently has. That works fine, but I want to display the updated value in another link instead. Example:

[image]

The function:

```
$(function() {
    $(".fav").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
        var parent = $(this);

        $(this).fadeOut(300);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ajax/post_like.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                parent.html(html);
                parent.fadeIn(300);
            } 
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

How the HTML looks like:

```
<a href="#" class="post-reaction pull-right fav" id="{$p->pid}"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="post-reaction pull-right"><i class="fa fa-retweet"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="post-reaction notes pull-right">{$p->notes}</a>
```

How can I achieve this? I'm still in the process of learning javascript. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're looking to do is increment it by 1 you can add this to your success:

```
var val = parseInt($(".notes").text());
$(".notes").text(val+1);
```

Otherwise, if the return from your AJAX, "html", is the number you want to use just replace

```
parent.html(html);
```

with

```
$(".notes").text(html);
```

**Update:**

Based on your comment, try this:

```
parent.parent().find(".notes").text(html);
```

This will get the closest `notes` (presumably the one you want to update) and change it's text.

Comment: I replaced parent.html(html); with $(".notes").text(html); and it kinda works, but it also updates the notes of all posts in the page, instead of just one.

Comment: The updated answer still doesn't work :/ it just simply does nothing now.

Comment: @Adrian.S Updated, try again. That may not be the cleanest solution though.